# Sonar with 6.7.1 version is not started

Tags: sonarqube, centos7

I've installed following sonar version `6.7.1` on centos `7.3` box.

But unfortunately it is not started due to some reason.

Please find logs for sonar and elastic search services below.

There is log for elastic search:

```
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initializing ...
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (rootfs)]], net usable_space [283.4gb], net total_space [357.4gb], spins? [unknown], types [rootfs]
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [494.9mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [8d_aB1EOTWarX8gUfkpMuw]
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] version[5.6.3], pid[14826], build[1a2f265/2017-10-06T20:33:39.012Z], OS[Linux/3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_144/25.144-b01]
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] JVM arguments [-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true, -Xms512m, -Xmx512m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Des.path.home=/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [ingest-common]
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [percolator]
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [reindex]
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
2018.02.25 14:41:40 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded
2018.02.25 14:41:42 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery type [zen]
2018.02.25 14:41:42 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized
2018.02.25 14:41:42 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ...
2018.02.25 14:41:42 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2018.02.25 14:41:45 INFO  es[][o.e.c.s.ClusterService] new_master {sonarqube}{8d_aB1EOTWarX8gUfkpMuw}{Hj4sSEGZRmCitocmSTu1Bg}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}{rack_id=sonarqube}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
2018.02.25 14:41:45 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] started
2018.02.25 14:41:45 INFO  es[][o.e.g.GatewayService] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2018.02.25 14:41:48 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopping ...
2018.02.25 14:41:48 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] stopped
2018.02.25 14:41:48 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closing ...
2018.02.25 14:41:48 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] closed
```

There is log for sonar:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.02.25 14:41:39 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonarqube/temp
2018.02.25 14:41:39 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.02.25 14:41:39 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonarqube/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonarqube/temp/conf/es
2018.02.25 14:41:39 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2018.02.25 14:41:39 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.02.25 14:41:39 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.02.25 14:41:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2018.02.25 14:41:45 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [/opt/sonarqube]: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_144/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-42.1.4.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process5168154533575436036properties
2018.02.25 14:41:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2018.02.25 14:41:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.02.25 14:41:48 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 143
2018.02.25 14:41:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Can someone suggest what was wrong during the start?

Answer (score 1):

I've just figured out what was my problem. Actually it was related to db credentials. I've tried to set up it once more time. I've change my password in two places:

- sonar.properties: `sonar.jdbc.password=newpassword`
- posgres db: `ALTER USER sonar WITH ENCRYPTED password 'newpassword';`

As result sonar was started successfully.